# no module named disutils.core

Tags: python, importerror

I have installed the 64 bit version of the Anaconda python distribution on my Windows 64 bit machine. I am trying to cythonize a python script and I get an error at the following line:

```
from disutils.core import setup
ImportError: No module named disutils.core
```

I tried

```
import disutils
ImportError: No module named disutils
```

Based on the information at the following link :
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#windows-7-or-graphical-install
I downloaded and ran ez_setup.py

I still get the same error. Can anyone help me solve my problem ?

Comment: Fix: The module was distutils and NOT disutils.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from disutils.core import setup
```

should be:

`from distutils.core import setup`

You have spelled it  `disutils` and `distuils` both missing a `t`

`import distuils` should be `distutils`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in my post here. However, I typed disutils correctly on my computer

Comment: No worries, easy mistake to make